# How to remove watermarks from porcelain sinks?

Tags: bathroom, cleaning, sink, stain

I bought a new (ceramic) soap dispenser a couple of weeks back and now there's a watermark on my porcelain sink where I used to keep it (picture below with increased contrast).  First off, I don't think it's a hard-water stain.  There's always a layer of water between the soap dispenser and the sink.  I think this water caused the stain (it smelled very bad too -- like ammonia and rotten eggs).  Any ideas on how to remove the stain?

[image]

**EDIT:** After some investigation it seems that such stains are caused due the porcelain absorbing water.  This is more common with granite counters and to prevent further staining, the granite has to be "resealed".

Comment: If it smells, it's not a watermark, but mold.

Answer (score 1):

Wipe with a paper towel with detergent, then apply chlorine bleach, small amount, let sit a few minutes then wipe off so someone doesn't come along unaware and ruin some clothes or worse get it in eyes. This can be Bon Ami with bleach, Tilex, etc., or can be chlorine laundry bleach.

Comment: Thanks, bleaching worked.  I didn't have chlorine bleach around, so I used hydrogen peroxide instead, and the stain is almost invisible now.

Comment: I use hydrogen peroxide some times. It is a milder oxidizing agent than chlorine bleach but will do for some purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mix your own stain remover but here goes 3 different methods you can use. The last method use with caution and at your own risk.

1. A mixture of Cream of Tarter and Vinegar - then use a brush.
2. Equal parts of Cream of Tarter and Hydrogen Peroxide - then use a brush.
3. Cottonball with Nail Polish remover - some reports say this will cause porcelain to explode apart, some say it works (it ruins marble). If you use this method - I recommend you thoroughly wash the area with water extensively and immediately.